# I have some information on an unknown (according to net) virus / app

Tags: support, answering-questions

I have some information that I would like to share with the community. I posted it on Stack Overflow and have been told to post it here somewhere. Could you point me in the right direction. There is no question involved. Just information.

Comment: Unless you can make a question then nowhere on Stack Exchange is suitable. Perhaps you should write a blog post somewhere?

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to a security researcher or company such as McAfee? If it is an actual question about a virus and a solution on how to remove it then *maybe* here on [su], but it wouldn't be on topic if you are just looking to examine the behaviour of it without solving a specific problem.

Comment: I'm assuming you are referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200387/rougue-app-virus-thing-2004-act-exe). If you convert it into a question of the "I was infected by x. It did this and that. What do I do?" and then post an answer showing steps taken to remove it then it could be on topic, but bear in mind that we do have some generic malware removal advice at [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit).

Comment: Nothing you describe in your SO is actually new behavior.  The malware is destructive.  If it doesn't encrypt your files because of an unpatched exploit that effects every version of Windows, from my perspective, the existing answer on how to remove malware is more then enough.  An additional answer/question for generic malware removal isn't helpful in my opionion.